# How to run app on App Engine for free

Tags: google-app-engine, billing

I am trying to run Parse Server, a Node.js app, on Google App Engine. And I am on trial period with $300 free credit.

From this page, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas, it says there is 28 free instance-hours per day. The app is running with 2 instances and, according to the report, my account is being charged for Compute Engine (G1 Small) for 48 hours everyday.

So how could I benefit from that 28 free hours?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 28 free instance-hours per day for frontend instances only when you are using one of the **standard environments** or runtimes(python, java, php and go) and not when you're using app engine's managed VMs. All [managed VM environments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) are based on Compute Engine and are all billable.

For a nodejs app, you're certainly using a managed VM.

To enjoy the free instance hours you'll need to use one of [the standard runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment).

Comment: Thank you very much. That's clear to me. I am looking for the way to run Parse Server (as Parse.com is going to shutdown soon) I have many small apps. Heroku starts at $7 per app which I cannot afford. I though GAE would fit because I could just pay for the app with high traffic, and free for the lower one. Now, I have to look for another Paas platform :(

Answer (score 3):

For the answer below me , nodejs now is one of the standard environments right now, so you basically can run your nodejs app for free