# Hosting web applications on GAE using several free tier

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have **several web applications**, and I would like to **host them on Google App Engine**. Recently, it seems to me the [pricing has changed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) and the free tier is now **based on quotas**. I have thought about the following:

Considering the applications requirements and the new quotas, the free tier on GCP should allow me to freely host only one webapp. What about **giving to each of my clients a billed GCP account**, and hosting his webapp on his own google project using his account, **to get as many free tier as webapps** ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard runtime apps on app engine free tier have always been quota-based https://stackoverflow.com/a/35590492/2295256 and that applies to each app engine app per project.

If you're on app engine standard, it shouldn't matter much as each project is entitled to a free tier. The number of projects per account is limited though but *can be* increased upon request.

Comment: I didn't know each project is entitled to a free tier, I was sure I could not have more than one per google account. Thank you for your response !